# mongoengine nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I am trying to connect to my heroku mongo database.
My connecting URL looks like this

I've replaced my actual username/password in the example below.

```
mongodb://username:password@ds135522.mlab.com:35522/heroku_brpg2n9r
```

I then have my config set up like this:

```
mongo_uri = os.environ.get('MONGOLAB_URI')

if mongo_uri:

        MONGODB_SETTINGS = {
            'db': mongo_uri.split('/')[-1],
            'host': mongo_uri
        }
    else:
        MONGODB_SETTINGS = {
            'db': 'local',
            'host': '127.0.0.1'
        }
```

I then export `MONGOLAB_URI=mongodb://username:password@ds135522.mlab.com:35522/heroku_brpg2n9r`

When I try an connec to database it gives me the following error:

```
ServerSelectionTimeoutError: heroku_brpg2n9r:27017: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it had to do with my mongoengine version.
I installed these modules and it started working as expected:

```
flask-mongoengine==0.7
mongoengine==0.8.7
pymongo==2.8.1
```